# SQL, return rows if there is no data in specified date

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 2 tables in an Oracle DB. One is containing static data, the `info_table`, and the other includes daily updated data, the `stats_table`. The `info_table` contains static data for each WCEL_ID (coordinates etc..), and the `stats_table` is being updated automatically everyday.

Sometimes, it is possible to get no data for any WCEL_ID, so in any particular date, any WCEL_ID may be missing in stats_tabel. My problem is, when I query data for a week for example, I only get data for days where specified WCEL_ID has an entry in `stats_table`, but I want to get `null` if there is no data for specific date.
Below is my query

`select *`
`FROM stats_table a full join info_table e`
`on a.WCEL_ID = e.WCEL_ID`
`where`
`a.period_start_time >= Trunc(sysdate-7) and a.WCEL_ID = '14000004554984'`

This return only one row, since we have no data for `a.WCEL_ID = '14000004554984'` for 6 days, but I want to have one row + 6 rows with nulls.

How can I implement the correct query?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Just use outer join and secondly you need to put conditions on info_table and not stats table since stats_table has lesser data[, so i will write this query something like:

```
select *
FROM stats_table a, info_table e
where a.WCEL_ID(+) = e.WCEL_ID
and e.period_start_time >= Trunc(sysdate-7) and e.WCEL_ID = '14000004554984'
```

Notice the chages i have made to "and e.period_start_time >= Trunc(sysdate-7) and e.WCEL_ID = '14000004554984'" , this is based on assumption that info_table has all the data and stats_table might be missing the data as has been stated by you.

EDIT:After comments from user edited the query

```
select *
    FROM stats_table a, info_table e
    where a.WCEL_ID(+) = e.WCEL_ID
    and a.period_start_time >= Trunc(sysdate-7) and e.WCEL_ID = '14000004554984'
```

EDIT:

On second thought i think the query is incomplete, there has to be a date column in info_table otherwise you cannot map data by date rows in 2 tables[without this you can't achieve what you want]. Taking that assumption , i am modifying query as below:

```
select *
    FROM stats_table a, info_table e
    where a.WCEL_ID(+) = e.WCEL_ID
    and e.period_start_time >= Trunc(sysdate-7) and e.WCEL_ID = '14000004554984'
    and a.period_start_time(+) = e.period_start_time
```

EDIT:
 I get your point now. You want to have a row for each day, and if data is present for that day then it should be displayed or else null should come. I modified my logic to include a nested query [having alias b] which will generates rows for each of past 7 days and put it in outer join with your main table. Try this and let me know if it resolves your issue.

```
SELECT * 
FROM stats_table a,
  info_table e,
  (SELECT to_date(sysdate-7,'dd-mon-yyyy') +rownum dates
  FROM all_objects
  WHERE rownum <= to_date(sysdate,'dd-mon-yyyy')-to_date(sysdate-7,'dd-mon-yyyy')
  ) b
WHERE a.WCEL_ID            = e.WCEL_ID
AND a.period_start_time(+) = b.dates
AND a.WCEL_ID              = '14000004554984'
```

Comment: the `period_start_time` field is only contained in `stats_table` actually. The `info_table` has multiple rows/entries for each WCEL_ID but `stats_table` has only one entry for each WCEL_ID element.

Comment: the `period_start_time` field is not available for `info_table`. Actually, `info_table` holds the static data like coordinates, alias names etc... It is the `stats_table` having multiple rows (one row for each day if there is data for particular WCEL_ID) for each WCEL_ID, whereas `info_table` has one entry for each WCEL_ID without any date/time information.

Comment: Thanks for update lpki, but the query returned no rows actually. You have the logic indeed. The problem is, it becomes difficult (a least for me) if there is no data for any specific date,then we have to "detect" there is no data for this day, and return `null`s instead.

Answer (score 0):

move the where clause to the join criteria or add an or to the and

`and (a.WCEL_ID is null OR a.WCEL_ID = '14....')`

```
select *
FROM stats_table a full join info_table e
on a.WCEL_ID = e.WCEL_ID
and a.period_start_time >= Trunc(sysdate-7) and a.WCEL_ID = '14000004554984'
```

Comment: If we add the clause "and (a.WCEL_ID is null OR a.WCEL_ID = '14....')" then for WCEL_ID = null what value will come from info_table?? I dont think this will work. You need outer join.

Comment: Thanks xQbert, but this did not return the desired result actually.